# Angular2 Using left hand side operator when calling functions in template

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following function in my component :

```
public limit: number = 3

public logLimit(limit) {
  console.log(limit)
}
```

and in my template :

```
<div (click)="logLimit(--limit)">Decrease and log limit</div>
```

However, the limit which is logged is 3 when I click on my div, how come my `--` operator didn't work ?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this is not supported.

You can use

```
<div (click)="limit = limit - 1;logLimit(limit)">Decrease and log limit</div>
```

Angular2 template bindings don't support full TS/JS syntax. This is not an issue but intentional.

Comment: How does that work if I want to set a condition on my click : (click)="condition && limit = limit - 1; logLimit(limit)" doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: You have to be careful with expressions in event handlers. If the result is `false` this causes `$event.preventDefault()` to be called. Try to add `;true` at the end.

Comment: I meant, this doesn't decrease the limit but log the result. I fixed it by doing : (click)="condition && limit = limit - 1; condition && logLimit(limit)" which is ugly though.

Comment: It would be better to create a method and do this stuff there. To much logic in the template is considered bad practice anyway.